# Difference between chain(*iterable) vs chain.from_iterable(iterable)

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have been really fascinated by all the interesting iterators in `itertools`, but one confusion I have had is the difference between these two functions and why `chain.from_iterable` exists.

```
from itertools import chain

def foo(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield [i, i**2]

chain(*foo(5))

chain.from_iterable(foo(5))
```

What is the difference between the two functions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The former can only handle unpackable iterables. The latter can handle iterables that cannot be fully unpacked, such as infinite generators.

Consider

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> def inf():
...     i=0
...     while True:
...         i += 1
...         yield (i, i)
... 
>>> x=inf()
>>> y=chain.from_iterable(x)
>>> z=chain(*x)
<hangs forever>
```

Furthermore, just the act of unpacking is an eager, up-front-cost activity, so if your iterable has effects you want to evaluate lazily, `from_iterable` is your best option.

Comment: BTW, `inf` in this example is practically the same as `itertools.count`

Comment: The example code here won't work regardless; `inf` isn't an iterable of iterables, it's an iterable of scalars, so only `chain(x)` would work. `chain(*x)` is admittedly worse (it wouldn't even successfully make the call, where `chain.from_iterable(x)` would return immediately and only die with a `TypeError` when you ask for a value from it), but both examples are bad. `yield (i, i)` or something would make the example sane.

Answer (score 8):

`chain(*foo(5))` unpacks the whole generator, packs it into a tuple and processes it then.

`chain.from_iterable(foo(5))` queries the generator created from `foo(5)` value for value.

Try `foo(1000000)` and watch the memory usage go up and up.

Answer (score 4):

`*` unpacks the iterator, meaning it iterates the iterator in order to pass its values to the function. `chain.from_iterable` iterates the iterator one by one lazily.