# combine lists in list/dict comprehension way

Tags: python, list-comprehension

is it possible to apply list/dictionary comprehension to the following code to have `["abc", "ab", "cd"]`

```
tk = {}
tk[1] = ["abc"]
tk[2] = ["ab", "cd"]
tk[3] = ["ef", "gh"]
t = (1, 2)
combined = []
combined.append(tk[i]) for i in t #does not work. note, not all tk values are used, this is based on t.
```

I could think of 
`ll = [tk[i] for i in t]`, then this turns to be [flatten list out of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python). so

```
ll = [tk[i] for i in t]
[item for sublist in ll for item in sublist]
```

but this is not one-liner. I wonder if there is better way.

Comment: Why do you need a list comprehension when you can just do: `tk[1] + tk[2]`?

Comment: You should use `extend` instead of `append`, and you may benefit from `itertools.chain`. Also pay attention at braces

Comment: this is only an illustrative example. I have a long sequence to iterate.

Comment: This is typically referred to as list flattening. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: @Meccano do *NOT* use list-comprehensions with side-effects. You can simply do `[s for v in tk.values() for s in v]`, anyway (order not guaranteed).

Answer (score 2):

If the order of values in the desired list matters, the generalized way to achieve this would be to sort the items in the `dict` based on the *key*, and merge the list of values. For example:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import chain

>>> list(chain.from_iterable(i for _, i in sorted(tk.items(), key=itemgetter(0))))
['abc', 'ab', 'cd']
```

Comment: One should prefer `chain.from_iterable` over splatting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533052/difference-between-chainiter-vs-chain-from-iterableiter

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for pointing that out. I should have used `chain.from_iterable` at the first place

Comment: Yep. I used to prefer the *look* of the splatting version, until I thought about it and realized that it would have to consume the iterable into a tuple and process it from there!

Answer (score 2):

Simply iterate through the values of your dictionary. Something like this:

```
>>> tk = {}
>>> tk[1] = ['abc']
>>> tk[2] = ['ab', 'cd']
>>> combined = [x for t in tk.values() for x in t]
>>> print combined
['abc', 'ab', 'cd']
```

You can even use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) if you need to maintain the order of your lists, since a regular `dict` does not guarantee the order of its keys:

```
>>> import collections
>>> tk = collections.OrderedDict()
>>> tk[1] = ['abc']
>>> tk[2] = ['ab', 'cd']
>>> combined = [x for t in tk.values() for x in t]
>>> print combined
['abc', 'ab', 'cd']
```

Note that `[tk[i] for i in (1, 2)]`, as you proposed, won't have the desired results. You still need to iterate through the values inside each list.

```
>>> [tk[i] for i in (1, 2)]
[['abc'], ['ab', 'cd']]
```

Also note that `[tk[i] for i in tk]`, as you proposed later, is exactly the same as `tk.values()`. So you could the proposed solution `[x for t in tk.values() for x in t]` is equivalent to what you achieved but in one line.

Answer (score 1):

Given your constraint of choosing a sequence of keys manually:

```
>>> tk = {}
>>> tk[1] = ["abc"]
>>> tk[2] = ["ab", "cd"]
>>> tk[3] = ["ef", "gh"]
```

You want:

```
>>> [vals for i in (1,2) for vals in tk[i]]
['abc', 'ab', 'cd']
```